# Word 2013 paragraph border/shading consistent to page border (and table border/shading)

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

How can I adjust a paragraph border/shading in Word 2013 to exactly match the page borders (like a table would do)?

Despite all indentions and distances from text have been set to 0, the paragraph borders stick over the defined page borders.

[image: Screenshot showing inconsistency between paragraph border/shading and page border]